# Intermediate fan speed i8k

Tags: drivers, kernel, dell, fan, fancontrol

On i8kfan you have just two options of fan speed. What i want is to know if there's a way to set a intermediate(or more than one) fan speed because the high value(2) is too noisy and the low value(1) let my system heat too much when watching videos or gaming.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't think so, but you could create a launcher to activate and deactivate the fans being set for high speed... There is a manual page [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/i8kctl.1.html), but that does not help much...

Comment: Well, i must thank you!!! That man page has a info that i did not know, which is that i8kmon also controls the fan speed and more importantly, using the -a option it sets the fan speed to 11000 rpm which is exaclty the intermediate between the i8kfan values low(~8000rpm) and high(~14000rpm).

It seems to work very well... Thanks!

Comment: Wow... I should read things properly... You might as well add it as an answer then :-)

Comment: You're right, wilf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page that wilf commented about has a info that i did not know, which is that i8kmon also controls the fan speed and more importantly, using the -a(automatic mod) option it sets the fan speed to 11000 rpm(and other values, of course) which is exaclty the intermediate between the i8kfan values low(~8000rpm) and high(~14000rpm).